# google sheets emails onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The case is I have a google sheet, that has a column that gets edited and 3 columns next to it that include a check, an email body and an email subject.
I made the following code so that when a certain cell is edited in the edit column, an email is sent for notification. I put the email in a column that is referred to in the code.

```
function onEdit(e){

//Detecting the edited cell and fetching the values from the other columns
  var range = e.range;
  var check = range.offset(0,2).getValue()
  var serial = range.offset(0,-1).getValue()
  var email = range.offset(0,-8).getValue()
  var message = range.offset(0,3).getValue()
  var subject = range.offset(0,4).getValue()
  if (check == "SendEmail") { var email2 = email; }

//Checks to see if the code is running
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('R1').setValue(email2)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('S1').setValue(check)

//Email part  
  var emailAddress = email2;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message)


}
```

When I try using the function without the on edit feat, the email is sent. when I, however, put the onEdit back on, it works perfectly still but no emails are sent.

Answer (score 2):

Please confirm whether `onEdit(e)` is installed as a trigger. When you use `MailApp.sendEmail()`, it is required authorization. So `onEdit(e)` without Installable Triggers cannot run `MailApp.sendEmail()`. How to install `onEdit(e)` as a trigger is as follows.

- On script editor
- Edit -> Current project's triggers -> Click here to add one now.
- For "Run", set "onEdit"
- For "Events", set "From spreadsheet" and "On edit"
- Click Save button

After this, please try again.

The detail information of Installable Triggers is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

If this was not useful, I'm sorry.

#### Edit :

This is a sample for confirming running `MailApp.sendEmail()`. When you use this, please install `onEdit()` as a trigger.

```
function onEdit() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("### your e-mail address ###", "Sample subject", "Sample body");
}
```

Comment: Well, I am already doing that :/ there are 2 command lines that I put to test whether the code is running or not by pasting values in cells that i can see in the spreadsheet. and they work perfectly, but no emails are sent. Tried using the code with no triggers on a single cell and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Mohamed Hassan Allam I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it and try the sample. If above sample didn't work, please tell me. At that time, please retrieve the error at View -> Execution transcript. If above sample works, itis found that there are errors except for ``MailApp.sendEmail()``.

Comment: I removed the trigger all together from the current project triggers and reinstalled the trigger and it worked! thank you so much

Comment: @Mohamed Hassan Allam I'm glad to hear that. But I apologize I was not useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing issues because your function name overlaps with the expected name of a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) function - merely naming a function `onOpen` or `onEdit` is sufficient to make that function run under "simple trigger" environment.

If you rename your function to something more pertinent - such as `sendNotification(e)`, then the only way it will run after cells are edited is if it is called via an [**installed trigger**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) - one created manually by a user, or programmatically.